# WPF PasswordBox & SecureString: Can't MakeReadOnly()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, passwordbox, securestring

Is it possible to mark the `PasswordBox.SecurePassword` as `ReadOnly`?

Consider this simple code:

XAML:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <PasswordBox Name="pBox" MinWidth="100" />
    <Button Content="OK" Click="Button_Click" Width="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pBox.SecurePassword.MakeReadOnly();
    Console.WriteLine(pBox.SecurePassword.IsReadOnly());
}
```

It will output `False`. Why?

**EDIT**: Just to make sure, I tried this and it output "True" as expected.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SecureString s = new SecureString();
    s.MakeReadOnly();
    Console.WriteLine(s.IsReadOnly());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pBox.SecurePassword` will return an new instance of secure string each time you read the property. You can validate it by calling `GetHashCode` on `pBox.SecurePassword` multiple times.

You'll also notice that using Visual Studios "Make object id" does not display #X, because its an new instance every time you hover with the mouse.

When creating a reference to a `SecureString` object into a local variable it *is* the same instance that you called `MakeReadOnly()` on, so it behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it perfectly. Do you have any idea why it was designed to return a copy of the SecureString? An extra layer of security?

Comment: I think since the `SecurePassword` is readonly, they really want it to be *read only*, so since `SecureString` is a reference type one could manipulate that instance, so it wouldn't be read only in they sence of immutable objects (like `System.String` is).